# flutter reduce time of navigation to main page

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication

I created Flutter app with integration firebase everything works perfectly, but I noticed something I want to know if this is normal behavior or not that something is

in `MaterialApp` widget I set home: like that `home: auth.isAuth ? MainPage() : AuthenticationPage(),`

`auth` is a provider of AuthenticationProvider, I change `auth` value dependens on `Firebase onAuthStateChanged`

```
 _firebaseAuth.onAuthStateChanged.listen((FirebaseUser account) async {
   //some condations
    auth = account
 })
```

the behavior, when I have authenticated before, is when app opened the splash screen show up then authentication page show for `auth` value check and change to true then move to `MainPage`

if that normal, is there any way best to reduce that time between splash and mainPage?

Answer (score 1):

When you restart the app, Firebase checks whether the user is still signed in before calling the `onAuthStateChanged` listener. Since this check requires a call to the servers, it may take some time.

If you want to optimistically assume that a user who was previously signed in, it still signed in, you can store a small token value in the [shared preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) of your app when the user is signed in. Then when your app starts, you check for that value, and if it exists, assume they're signed in and redirect.

In this case, you should/will only be showing data that is already on the device, since you can't retrieve any new data until the user's authentication state has been verified.

You'll still need to handle the `onAuthStateChanged` listener, just in case the user cannot be reauthenticated. In that case, you'll want to redirect them back to the sign-in page, to allow them to re-enter their credentials.

Comment: Thanks Frank I will try this way